# Swift and Alamofire - Accessing JSON value for a conditional statement

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to access values within my JSON data structure that are returned from my API call. I want to show the `shared` image only if the `shared` value in my JSON is true, otherwise show a different image. Currently, when I launch the app, the first two results do not show the image, since the value is set to false in the database. But when I scroll down and then scroll back up, they appear. I am bit confused how to use JSON to check a conditional. Am I checking the conditional for each row in the correct place? Would something like SwitfyJSON be a better approach to access my nested JSON data structure?

```
class FactsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

var data = [AnyObject]()
var id = String()

func callAPI() {

    let user = "user"
    let pass = "pass"
    let url = "https://example.com/api"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: nil)
        .authenticate(user: user, password: pass)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
            self.data = JSON! as [AnyObject]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.cacheFacts()
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("facts", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as FactTableViewCell
    cell.factTitle.text = data[indexPath!.row]["preferredPhrase"] as? String
    cell.factBody.text = data[indexPath!.row]["content"] as? String

// If the value of teamShared is true show image, else show something different

    if let shared = self.data[indexPath!.row]["shared"] as? Bool {
        var isShared = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 95, 15, 15)); // set as you want
        var isSharedImage = UIImage(named: "team.png");
        isShared.image = isSharedImage;
        cell.addSubview(isShared);

// This always prints true even if the JSON is set to false. Can't figure out why this is?

        println(shared)
    }

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: If always prints true, then why you not seeing the image at beginning?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems, 1st, you are using the cached cell but didn't clean them up. So you should do the cleaning before return it. 
2nd, the if let will return true as long as the unwrap succeeds. So you should check the value again.

Note: I didn't test the code, just for demo.

```
   cell.viewWithTag(333)?.removeFromSuperview() // Find the tag and remove it.
   if let shared = self.data[indexPath!.row]["shared"] as? Bool {
        if shared {
            var isShared = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 95, 15, 15)); // set as you want
            isShared.tag = 333  // Assign a tag to it
            var isSharedImage = UIImage(named: "team.png");
            isShared.image = isSharedImage;
            cell.addSubview(isShared);
            println(shared)
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you give an example of how to do this? I've done some searching and I can't seem to find a solution. I would think this should be documented if it's a common pattern?